# Angular: How to set proxy to avoid CORS error

Tags: angular, nginx, cors

In angular application I have proxy.conf.json in this way

```
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://10.127.152.161:8080",
    "secure": true,
    "changeOrigin": true
  },

  "/rest/*": {
    "target": "http://10.127.152.161:8080",
    "secure": true,
    "changeOrigin": true
  },

  "/auth/*": {
    "target": "http://10.127.152.161:8080",
    "secure": true,
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

Since in development mode, angular app runs on localhost:4200, setting target to ipv4 address:8080 is causing CORS Headers issue. For some reasons I have to use 
http://10.127.152.161:8080 not as localhost:8080 or 3000 port. I have added  **add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';** nginx conf file but no luck. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

set  `"secure"` property to `false`.

```
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://10.127.152.161:8080",
    "secure": false
},
...
```

Comment: `httpClient.get('10.127.152.161:8080/api/foo')`, `httpClient.get('/api/foo')`
which is your case?

Comment: It's **httpClient.get('/api/foo')**

Answer (score 0):

set "secure": false and "changeOrigin": false

```
"/api/*": {
        "target": "http://10.127.152.161:8080",
        "secure": false,
        "changeOrigin": false
      },
```